# Loading a network-retrieved asset into SoundPool

Tags: android

In the application I'm working on, we're switching to loading all app assets from a network store so that we can update them independently of app store submissions. However, it seems that `SoundPool` only allows loading directly from local storage, either via a hardcoded file path or via `AssetFileDescriptor`.

Are there some methods I'm just not seeing in the API, or do I really have to download the network resource, write it out to a temporary file, and then have `SoundPool` load it back in from that file?

Note that this is still for UI sound effects that are intended to be pooled, stored in memory, and played with minimal latency.  I am not asking for a mechanism for streaming audio from the network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android Developer site says

"A SoundPool is a collection of samples that can be loaded into memory from a resource **inside** the APK or from a file in the file system."

It also mentions that an audio file for the SoundPool must be located in the res/raw folder. There doesn't appear to be support for pooling resources over a network in SoundPool, however [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) supports audio streaming.

Comment: I'm not asking for streaming, though - this is for pooled UI sound effects, which just happen to be located on the network. I've edited my question to clarify.

Comment: Then I think you'll have to download them in the background and load them into the SoundPool later. The documentation appears to only mention loading resources locally.

Comment: Okay, that's what I was afraid of.